# Knockout dropdown options render callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've always used [Harvest's Chosen dropdown](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which requires some js called to be called on a `<select>` item. Now, I'm rendering my select lists with Knockout.

This is the code used to transform a standard dropdown in a Chosen dropdown

```
$(dropdownSelectorOrElement).Chosen()
```

I need to know **when** Knockout has finished rendering the `<select>`, in order to call the code above: possibly, the callback function should reference the `<select>` itself so that I can pass without the use of selectors.

Knockout exposes the `optionsAfterRender` callback (documented [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html): see "note 2") however:

- `optionsAfterRender` gets called every time an option is rendered
- `optionsAfterRender` provides only a reference to the option element

I need exactly something like `optionsAfterRender` but called only when the entire `<select>` has finished rendering. Does knockout have anything like this?

I've prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n6TU/) which illustrates `optionsAfterRender`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved with this custom binding found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165246/knockout-linked-dropdownlist-ko-observablearray-chosen-plugin).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        $(element).chosen();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); // - see comment
        $(element).trigger("liszt:updated");
    }
};
```

Note that if you don't use `ko.unwrap`, the update function will not fire, as it has been told to me in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856994/custom-bind-to-observable-array-not-calling-update-function) question relating to this issue.

Comment: Thanks this works, but unfortunately not always. It depends on the order of bindings and subscriptions for the valueAccessor() observable.

Answer (score 1):

Could also create an afterRender binding :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.afterRender = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        allBindings.get('afterRender').call(viewModel, element);
    }
};
```

With this view :

```
<select data-bind="
options: Options,
value: selection,
optionsText: 'text',
optionsValue: 'value',
afterRender: renderCallback
"></select>
<span data-bind="text: selection"></span>
```

And this View model :

```
function viewModel() {

    this.renderCallback = function (selectElement) {
        console.log('call');
    };

    this.Options = [{
        text: "abee",
        value: "123"
    } ...
};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9n6TU/2/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is do not work with knockout 3.4, except you have subscription to a model observable in the callback or binding.