# Custom bind to observable array not calling update function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this very simple binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        console.log("INIT");
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        console.log("IT WORKS!");
    }
};
```

Used in a select:

```
<select data-bind="
        options: Options,
        chosen: Options
    "></select>
```

`Options` is declared as:

```
this.Options = ko.observableArray(opt1);
```

And updated, when necessary, like this:

```
this.Options(newValues);
```

However, `"IT WORKS"` gets logged only one time (when the select list is rendered) and never again. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzTg4/7/). Try to press the "reload" button: the array is updated, the select list re-rendered (yay!) but the custom update function isn't called (nay!). I even tried to force `.valueHasMutated` but with no success.

I need the update function to work properly. Why isn't this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't happening because you don't use `valueAccessor` in update function. If you used it you would get `update` function fired:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        console.log("INIT");
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        console.log("IT WORKS!");
    }
};
```

Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzTg4/8/

Comment: can I build you a statue?